# Registering future state after login using ui-router-extras-future-state module

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-router-extras

Myself trying to register a future state after login based on user type.

For example:
If `user_type` is `buyer`, then I need to register all routers that I maintained from `futureStates_buyer.json`

If `user_type` is `admin`, then I need to register all routers that I maintained from `futureStates_admin.json`

**Experiment 1 (As per sample)**

Sample URL: http://christopherthielen.github.io/ui-router-extras/example/future/

I can set the following configuration in config phase. I understand that provider settings should be inside config phase.

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $futureStateProvider) {

 $futureStateProvider.stateFactory('ngload', ngloadStateFactory); 
 $futureStateProvider.addResolve(loadAndRegisterFutureStates);

});
```

Working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/9dUm0f6g2V5PM4m7YlTD?p=preview

**Experiment 2 (This is what I am trying)**

but, In my case, I don't want to register all the routers for the entire application in config phase. it will be very high configuration. So what I am trying is, once logged in, I can get the user type in login response, based on that user type, I need to register the future states.

```
//config phase
app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $futureStateProvider) {

 //Planned to use futureStateProvider later in controller
  lazyLoad = {stateProvider: $stateProvider, futureStateProvider:$futureStateProvider};

});


//Login controller
app.controller('LoginController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$state', '$http', function($scope, $rootScope, $state, $http) {

     $scope.doLogin = function(){

            //After successfull login
            //Service invocation comes here
            console.log("Logged in!!");
            $rootScope.userInfo = {"loggedIn" : true };
            $state.go('dashboard');

            //Now I want to register future state based on login response i.e user_type
            // If user type is buyer, I want to registrer futureStates_buyer.jsom
            // If user type is vendor, I want to registrer futureStates_vendor.jsom

            lazyLoad.futureStateProvider.stateFactory('ngload', ngloadStateFactory); // register AngularAMD ngload state factory
            lazyLoad.futureStateProvider.addResolve(loadAndRegisterFutureStates);

        }

}]);
```

Not working: http://plnkr.co/edit/pCEKLopOqSKghermTHP8?p=preview

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I have used your code, But when I reload the page it is redirecting me on the login page. This is issue. How you have resolved this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have fixed the issue by changing the code in `controller` section as follows and it is working fine.

```
   //Login controller
    app.controller('LoginController', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$state', '$http', function($scope, $rootScope, $state, $http) {
        $scope.login = {"username":"admin", "password":"admin123"};

        $scope.doLogin = function(){

            //After successfull login
            //Service invocation comes here
            console.log("Logged in!!");
            $rootScope.userInfo = {"loggedIn" : true };


            //Now I want to register future state based on login response i.e user_type
            // If user type is buyer, I want to registrer futureStates_buyer.jsom
            // If user type is vendor, I want to registrer futureStates_vendor.jsom

            /*          
            var loadAndRegisterFutureStates = function ($http) {
              // $http.get().then() returns a promise
              return $http.get('futureStates_buyer.json').then(function (resp) {
                angular.forEach(resp.data, function (fstate) {
                  // Register each state returned from $http.get() with $futureStateProvider
                  lazyLoad.futureStateProvider.futureState(fstate);
                });
              });
            };
            */

            $http.get('futureStates_buyer.json').then(function (resp) {
                angular.forEach(resp.data, function (fstate) {
                  // Register each state returned from $http.get() with $futureStateProvider
                  lazyLoad.futureStateProvider.futureState(fstate);
              });

              $state.go('dashboard');
      });

            lazyLoad.futureStateProvider.stateFactory('ngload', ngloadStateFactory); // register AngularAMD ngload state factory
            //lazyLoad.futureStateProvider.addResolve(loadAndRegisterFutureStates);

        }

    }]);
```

Working demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZXty2SkmGbuwnpaJoh7C?p=preview

Comment: Hi, Could you please share, How you have maintained the states when user reloads the page.